# Filtering SharePoint SiteMapDatasource

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using a SiteMapDatasource in a tree view to display a simple hierarchical site map.  I need to filter this map so that it only shows links to sites and sub sites, and not any links to things like lists, document libraries, etc.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your situation, would it be possible (assuming these are XML type data structures) to use some kind of XPATH query to pull and filter information?  Perhaps you can transform it via XSLT?  If you can post what things look like, it might help to give a little more insight.

There is always, the possibility of using LINQ on the data source...